# Direction of the vector

Tags: multivariable-calculus

What is the direction, in degrees and to 2 decimal places, for the vector whose column form is
\[
\begin{pmatrix} a & b \end{pmatrix}
\]
where $a = 19$ and $b = -5$?  Do not give any units in your answer.  Your answer must be between $-90°$ and $270°$.

I got the answer as $-75.26°$. I used

\[ \arctan \frac{19}{-5}\]

Comment: Is this a question?  It also sounds like a homework issue.

Comment: it is @kcrisman ! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Draw a picture, perhaps more or less to scale.  Note that the slope is "**rise**" divided by "**run**". Or, in symbols, the slope is the change in $y$ divided by the change in $x$.

Comment: haha i did and i got the answer so just verifying if it is correct tks

Comment: @JackyBoi: Do the picture as I suggested. Your answer is not correct. Picture will show that. Your expression is upside down.

Comment: any example? cause my textbook doesnot have such slope and rise concept perhaps i will learn.. tks

Comment: @JackyBoi: Change the problem slightly to $a=19$, $b=5$. The slope is $\frac{5}{19}$: the tangent of the angle is opposite divided by adjacent. For your problem, you will want $\arctan(-5/19)$.

Comment: so -14.74? is that the answer?

Comment: Sorry, busy. Yes, that's it.

Comment: ah ok but still thiking how u deduce it as slope and rise cocept.. intresting take on the question